# Facebook sdk 3.5 Integration issue

Tags: android, facebook

I am creating application in which have to integrate facebook sdk 3.5

Q :If there offical facebook app already exists in mobile then can i directly get login into facebook from my app without showing facebook Login dialog ?

in this case any sample code present (besides facebook SDK sample) please attach with
answers.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolve the issue with help of following [link](http://androideity.com/2012/07/20/android-single-sign-on-sso-con-facebook/)